# Unity3D: Change skybox color via script?

Tags: c#, colors, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in the engine Unity, and am trying to make the skybox change color based on the time of day, but I can't seem to find out how to get it working.. What I want to do, I think, is to change the color of the material I use for the skybox in render settings, and be able to set it using one variable for red, one for green and one for blue.

I am using C#.

Thanks in advance for all answers :)

Comment: What do you mean? I'm asking for an explaination of how to do it, not what's wrong with my own code..

Comment: See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/130529/change-tint-color-of-main-skybox-material-in-scrip.html Apparently it uses `_Tint` rather than `_Color`.

Comment: I tried this:
    RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", 0, 0, blue);
but I just got the error 
    "error CS1501: No overload for method `SetColor' takes `4' arguments"

Answer (score 8):

From the code you displayed in the comment:

RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", 0, 0, blue)

I think you mean

[RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", Color.blue)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html)

no need for extra zeros and remember that the color "[blue](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Color-blue.html)" is a member variable of the [Color class](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Color.html).

Next you would have to develop a time system and based on the time var you pass to the script controlling the skybox renderer you would then use a Lerp function to smoothly transition from one color to the next... like [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material-color.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class example : MonoBehaviour {
    public Color colorStart = Color.blue;
    public Color colorEnd = Color.green;
    public float duration = 1.0F;
    void Update() {
        float lerp = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration;
        RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", Color.Lerp(colorStart, colorEnd, lerp));
    }
}
```

Then you could write a function to change the colorStart and colorEnd...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

We can change Skybox color using the `_Tint` property. `RenderSettings` is the base class used to change the render properties at run time. For ensuring the attribute is existing in the skybox is done by the `HasProperty()`. `SetColor()` is used to set the color of the skybox.

```
     if (RenderSettings.skybox.HasProperty("_Tint"))
         RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_Tint", Color.red);
     else if (RenderSettings.skybox.HasProperty("_SkyTint"))
         RenderSettings.skybox.SetColor("_SkyTint", Color.red);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own skybox too in Unity by changing texture shape into a cube one then apply for those changes it will create a cube mesh which you can simply drop into your unity editor screen.

And if you want to load multiple skybox materials on run time by clicking on a button:

```
public class skybox : MonoBehaviour {

public Material[] secondSkybox;
    public static int i = 0;
    public void skyboxOn()
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            RenderSettings.skybox = secondSkybox[0];
            i++;
        }
        else if(i==1)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = secondSkybox[1];
            i++;
        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
            RenderSettings.skybox = secondSkybox[2];
            i=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and if you want too change the color of skybox which can be done by using this line of  code

```
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat ("_Exposure", Mathf.Sin (Time.time * Mathf.Deg2Rad * 100) + 2);
```